# How to move the whole scene in webGL and HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I want to move the whole scene in the canvas area in webGL.

I mean if I was using openGL. I would change the clipping window, but I think in webGL the big world is the canvas so I can't do the same in webGL!!

for example:
I have a canvas width: 1000, height: 500
2 squares: the first square is between 0 and 1000 on the X-axis so in the canvas area, and the second is bigger then 1000 on the X-axis.

so I want to click on the right arrow button, and the scene moves right until the other square appear !! with openGL I would simply draw them (the other square will not appear because I would set the gluOrtho2D to (0 ,1000) on the X-axis) then change the gluOrtho2D to (500, 1500) for instance then the other square will appear !! so how to do that using webGL ? I tried scissor function but i won't work because it appears that the canvas is the whole world .. so whatever is drawn outside will be ignored !!

Any ideas ?

Here is the code: I am trying to draw 1 triangle, then move the scene to view the second one completely. so I want the result to be the 2 triangles in the canvas drawn completely.

```
var gl;
var triangleBuffer;
var triangleBuffer2;
var squareBuffer;
var shaderprogram;

function initGL(canvas) {
    try {
      gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
      gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
      gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
    } catch(e) { }
    if (!gl) {
      alert("Could not initialise WebGL!");
    }
}

function getShader(gl, id) {
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!shaderScript) {
        return null;
    }

    var str = "";
    var k = shaderScript.firstChild;
    while (k) {
        if (k.nodeType == 3) {
    str += k.textContent;
        }
        k = k.nextSibling;
    }

    var shader;
    if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
    gl.compileShader(shader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        return null;
    }

    return shader;
}

function initShaders(){
    var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
    var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

    // Create a program (piece of code to run on the GPU)
    shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    // Attach the vertext and fragment shaders to the program then link them
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

    // If the linking failed
    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        alert("Could not initialise shaders");
    }

    // Set the current program
    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

    // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
    gl.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "a_position");

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

    var resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "u_resolution");
    gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
}

function initBuffers(){
    // Create buffer for the triangle
    triangleBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    // Set the current buffer to the triangle buffer, so any action or transformation will be done on this current buffer
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleBuffer);

    // One triangle inside the canvas coordinates, the other is not
    var vertices = [500, 250,
            600, 150,
            550, 250,
            900, 100,
            1100, 300,
            900, 200];
    // load the vertices array into the current buffer
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // This array consists of 3 items, each item consists of 3 numbers
    triangleBuffer.numItems = 6;
    triangleBuffer.itemSize = 2;
}

function drawScene(){
    gl.viewport(0, 0, 1000, 500);
    //gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleBuffer);
    // call the code the will operate on the current buffer
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, triangleBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    // Draw the first triangle
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    /* ======================================= here goes the moving of the scene ================== */

    // Draw the second triangle
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 3, 3);

}

function start() {

    // get the canvas element source
    var canvas = document.getElementById("game");

    initGL(canvas);
    initShaders();
    initBuffers();

    // Clear the canvas
    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    drawScene();
}
```

Here are the shaders:

```
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;

    void main(void) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
</script>

<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec2 a_position;
    uniform vec2 u_resolution;

    void main(void) {
        // convert from normal coordinates to clipspace coordinates(-1 to 1)
        vec2 clipSpace = ((a_position / u_resolution) * 2.0) - 1.0;
        gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace, 0, 1);

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Depends on what you are drawing, and how.

Comment: I want only to move the scene, without looking to the content of the scene. if I want to make a super mario game for example. I want when the character moves right the scene moves and new objects of the level appear.

Comment: I understand what you want, and what I am telling you is that it depends on what you are rendering, and how you are rendering it. There are many ways to render a scene, and how you move about it depends on how you are rendering it in the first place. Are you using a scene graph library? Have you implemented a scene graph? What do your shaders look like? [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

You introduce a projection and viewing matrix like so:

```
attribute vec3 position;
uniform mat4 proj, view;

void main(void){
    gl_Position = proj * view * vec4(position, 1);
}
```

The glMatrix library has the routines to setup these 4x4 matrices https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix

Alternatively you can lookup matrix formulas in Appendix F of the opengl programming guide (blue book).

Usually you choose the projection matrix to be a perspective projection and the view matrix to be a combination of translation/rotation.